# grub rescue command. grub not working in ubuntu 13

Tags: grub2

I have dual boot ubuntu and windows.

When I started my machine, it started with grub rescue >  command. I researched this, but couldn't solve the problem, so I tried to reinstall windows 7 and deleted the ubuntu hard drive.

This didn't solve the problem. and now I have a screen saying `grub rescue >` without ubuntu installed in my laptop.

So what can I do to to recover from this??
<sub>*Remember, I deleted the ubuntu setup files installed on my laptop*</sub>

Comment: Is Windows 7 still installed?

Comment: Read: [How to Restore the Windows 7 MBR (Master Boot Record)](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html). Since you don't have Ubuntu installed (and grub is not Ubuntu), this question is better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have had that happen to me once.  Here what you can do.  Try [Boot-Rpair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), and [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) first, if that doesn't help, then here's what you can do.

Boot from the Ubuntu LiveCD, and once booted, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install wipe
```

Once installed, find your drive's label using:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Once you get the device label, do:

```
sudo wipe /dev/sdaX
```

Replce X with your drives ID.

**The procedure is irreversible.  All data on the drive will be completely gone , and probably won't be able to recover.**

**You need to figure our the correct hard drive to wipe. If you wipe the wrong hard drive, that data will not be recoverable, so be extra careful!**

Comment: so u mean all the files i had stored will be erased?Isnt there any other way