# How can I delete everything off of my SSD hard drive, or namely the grub loader?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, sudo, delete

I'm currently using a live CD and I am attempting to delete everything off of my harddrive. So, I've used the command `sudo nautilus` and attempted to delete everything off of my SSD. However, I cannot delete the folder `rofs` (Read only file system). I generally would have absolutely no issues with this, however, I believe it is causing everything I delete to come back to life upon restarting the computer.

Prior to using Nautilus to do this, I've used `sudo shred -vz -n 1 /dev/sda2`, and `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2` but it doesn't seem to work. The grub loader still exists, I wish to demolish it, and preferably all other files.

How can I remove the grub loader, and if possible, how can I delete the `rofs` folder entirely?

Comment: Please provide exact commands you used.

Comment: Ah, my only real goal is to delete the grub loader from my harddrive. Do you know how I'd actually go about doing that? As err, explained in the OP :c

But, "sudo shred -vz -n 1 /dev/sda2"
And "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2"

And most recently, to launch Nautilus, "sudo nautilus"

Comment: And where is your GRUB installed? Also, do you mount namely `/dev/sda2` after cleaning? Do you have any other partitions on this SSD?

Comment: The Grub Loader is in /boot/grub, but deleting this does nothing as it seems to actually be located in the /rofs/boot/grub

May I ask what you mean by the mounting question?

No, no partitions. Just Unallocated Space.

Comment: Try to execute `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`. Mounting is the operation that precedes viewing disk contents.

Comment: Alright, that's been going for a good hour without any output whatsoever. I can't imagine writing 60GB of 0s to an SSD could take that long. Is there any way to access the read only file system to delete the grub loader?

Alright, a minute after I typed this, I received output. 

dd: writing to '/dev/sda': No space left on device
117231409+0 records in
117231408+0 records out
60022480896 bytes (60 GB) copied, 2351.47 s, 25.5 MB/s

It seems the drive still... Still has the grub loader.

Comment: How did you determine that it has boot loader? Looked into `/boot/grub` directory?

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321531/grub-rescue-command-grub-not-working-in-ubuntu-13/321540#321540), I believe it might help.

Answer (score 1):

IF your trying to delete everything, why not use

```
$sudo gparted
```

to simply reformat? That would get rid of everything... period.

Also ROFS might refer to the medium that the live distro is written/burned/saved on (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your grub resides on MBR, and by dd-ing all of /dev/sda2 you just get ride of your data, files and folders, not your boot loader.

On the other hand, If you loose your boot loader, you can't boot up with that disk at all.
So, after deleting the content, use

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

To remove that partition and write changes to table.
When that partition (dev/sda2) is completely gone and shown as free space, you're done. (still you can low-level format to make sure recovering is almost impossible.)

[Low-level formatting](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/low-level-formatting.html) is a procedure where you write data directly to the storage medium, bypassing the filesystem layer.